# async await in observer function

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I want to create an observable from which to push values to my observers.

The problem is, that those values are obtained via calling a promise-returning method.

Is there a way to call await on the promise-returning function within the observable, like the following pseudo-code (which does not work, because i can't mark the function passed to the observable async)...

```
return new Observable((observer) => {

  let counter = 0;

  for(...)
  {
    try
    {
      const value = await promisefunction(counter++);
                    ^^^^^
      observer.next(value);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      observer.complete();
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Whats the error?  `await` can be used only within `async` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most observable operators that consume an observable can also consume a promise.  So you can get what you want via `concatMap` and `defer`:

```
const observable = of(arrayOfObjects).pipe(
    concatMap((object, i) => defer(() => promiseFunction(object, i))
)
```

We use `defer` to defer actually executing `promisefunction` (and "starting" the promise) until the previous promise completes.  So the above construct will execute the function sequentially one at a time, just like you were trying to do with your async for loop.

Edit: You can also do it your way like so:

```
const observable = new Observable(observer => {
  let canceled = false;
  let count = 0;

  async function engine() {
    try {
      while (!canceled) {
        const value = await promiseFunction(++count);
        observer.next(value);
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      observer.error(e);
    }
  }

  engine();
  return () => canceled = true;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the returning of the lambda/arrow function, please?
Where will this be called by whom?

AFAIK this is called when unsubscribing.

Comment: Yep. That’s just giving Rx a way to tell you that the observer unsubscribed so you can stop your async generator if you want

Comment: Would using rxjs concat(promise 1, promise 2) not execute the 2 promises sequentially, such that you don't need to use defer?

Comment: @coder101 `concat` will certainly subscribe to promise2 only after promise1 completes.  However promises represent "hot" async work -- there is no way for a promise producer to be notified when someone "subscribes" to a promise thus the only way to really produce a promise is to proactively start the async action that will eventually resolve to a promise.  So in practice you'll find that `concat(p1, p2)` will start both the p1 async action and p2 async action long before `concat` actually executes.  `defer` is the way to delay the execution

Comment: @Brandon, so if want promise 2 to execute after promise 1 resolves, the correct way to achieve that with observables would be `concat(p1, defer(()=>p2))`?  I'm presuming we don't need concatMap here (instead of concat) since the source (a promise) emits only one item, right?